# How do I stop emacs from colouring the text of the file I am editing?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

How do I stop emacs from colouring the text of the file I am editing? I want everything just in plain white. I know that I can load themes, but it's not obvious which theme does what. Can I just disable all the colouring so that when I start emacs up, all the text is always white?

Comment: I have now done this.

Comment: The syntax highlighting depends on the major mode. `text-mode` should not involve any syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks - important for colorblind folks like me for whom the new colors and my background color look nearly identical....

Comment: I was looking for "how can I stop Emacs when it's stuck in color highlighting" which is here: https://superuser.com/questions/641124/how-to-interrupt-emacs-when-control-g-does-not-work-in-very-large-files

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Colours are provided by the font-lock minor mode.

To disable colouring in your current buffer, toggle font-lock-mode off with this command:

```
M-x font-lock-mode
```

To disable font-lock-mode permanently, add to your init file (~/.emacs):

```
(global-font-lock-mode 0)
```

More info is available under [Font-Lock in the Gnu Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot - what a relief not to have to see those colours again!